# is this use of realloc inside a function correct? (and the use of free() in case of failure)

Tags: c

I found some questions similar to this but there are some differences.
here is my code:
student.h:

```
#define NUM_GRADES 5
#define NAME_LENGTH 21
#define ADDRESS_LENGTH 21
    typedef struct
{
    char name[NAME_LENGTH]; //name of a student - up to 20 chars.
    char add[ADDRESS_LENGTH]; //address - up to 20 chars.
    int grades[NUM_GRADES]; //stores the grades of a student.
}student;

//the current size of the students array.
extern int currentTotal;

//add a new student space, return 0 if failed, 1 if succeeded.
int addStudent(student **studentClass);
```

student.c:

```
    int addStudent(student **studentClass)
{
    //adds the count for the new student.
    currentTotal++; 
    //a temporary pointer to hold studentClass array in case realloc fails.
    student *temp=NULL;
    //reallocating space for the new student.
    if (!(temp = (student*)realloc(*studentClass, currentTotal * sizeof(student))))
    {
        printf("Not enough memory.\n");
        free(*studentClass);//free the original array.
        currentTotal = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    *studentClass = temp;//point class to the newly allocated space.
    printf("Added space for a student.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "student.h"
void main()
{
    student *studentClass=NULL;
....
if(addStudent(&studentClass) 
....
```

currentTotal is an external int variable.
Is the use of realloc correct?
And the use of free? 
I always mix up whether I should use * or ** inside the function, once I send the address of a pointer to another function. (i.e. having a pointer like *studentClass and then sending &studentClass to another function).

if this is indeed correct then what happens to the original data that *studentClass pointed before the line
"*studentClass = temp;" (in student.c) ?
does it need to be freed?

edit:
Please don't be confused that initially *studentClass is NULL, it's only like that at the start, addStudent() is meant to be called in a loop, so after the first time, *studentClass is no longer NULL. addStudent() increase the size of *studentClass after each call.

Thanks.

Comment: It was fine to ask this here, but you should also be aware of https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  where you can get some good feedback about your code

Comment: thanks, i'll post there next time.

Comment: The sites are for different purposes.  In truth, you should not have posted this here. A post here should 1) show code 2) tell us what the code is supposed to do 3) explain how it is going wrong, and then we fix it. It's good that you got an answer, but you could could also have found it yourself with a good IDE (which do you use?) or by unit testing. Welcome aboard. We look forward to helping you - and to you helping others :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's "save" in the sense that it does not introduce undefined behaviour and it does not leak memory. You take care that if `realloc` fails, the original data is not freed (so you do it), and you store the result of `realloc` in a temp variable in  order not to loose the pointer to the original data. So far everything is OK.

It contains, however, a pitfall for the caller of `addStudent` if `realloc` fails. In this case, you free the original memory block without providing a new one, but you do not reset the pointer to `NULL`. So the variable  passed  to `addStudent` still  points to some memory, but this memory has been freed. A caller might attempt to free this memory a second time (yielding undefined behaviour then).

In case of `realloc` having  failed, I'd suggest to do either of two options depending on who shall be responsible for freeing student's array memory:

a. `addStudent` is responsible: Free the original memory AND set the pointer to `NULL`, such that no one outside can attempt to free memory twice. So you'd add a `*studentClass=NULL` after the `free`.

b. the caller is responsible: Don't free original memory in case of `realloc` failure; return - as you do - a failure code and let the caller do the rest. So you'd remove the `free`.

Comment: does it still matter that the pointer point somewhere after free if the program ends at that point? (if memory allocation fails then we are instructed to end the program, after freeing what should be freed). so I could instead of "return 0;" do "exit(1);" without setting the pointer to NULL, is that fine (in the sense of "safe")

Comment: There's no need to reset the pointer to `NULL`. `studentClass` is `NULL` at the call to `addStudent`, if `realloc(3)` fails the original pointer is unmodified, so it's still `NULL`.

Comment: It does not matter as long as you do not "use" (especially dereference) an invalid pointer. So no matter in your case, but a pitfall in general.

Comment: @bnaecker: if one relied on `*studentClass` being `NULL`, then `realloc` would not make sense at all. So I think OP should make the code a little bit more robust (but  only a  little bit :-) ).

Comment: @bnaecker its NULL only at the start...please see edit to the question, is it still correct? I am increasing the size of *studentClass in each call to addStudent()

Answer (score 0):

This is all fine. Because `*studentClass` is `NULL`, `realloc(3)` behaves just like `malloc(3)`. In the case that `realloc(3)` fails, it does not modify the passed pointer, meaning that `*studentClass` is still `NULL`. Calling `free(3)` on a `NULL` pointer is perfectly valid, but nothing will happen (a no-op). Then the function returns, and `*studentClass` is still `NULL`. You just need to check its value after the call to `addStudent`: if it's `NULL` the addition of a student failed, otherwise it succeeded.

Your use of double-pointers is also valid. One way to reason about this is like so. Pointers allow modification of the data at the pointed-to location. If one wants to pass an integer to a function to be modified, one can pass it as an `int*`. Inside the function, one dereferences it to modify it, such as `*my_int = 0;`. So if one wants to modify a `student*` inside a function, it must be passed as a `student**` and then dereferenced whenever one wants to change its contents.

Comment: but *studentClass is NULL only at the start of the program, addStudent() is meant to be called in a loop, if realloc fails at the 2nd/3rd/4th ... iteration, is it still fine like this? thanks

Comment: about the pointers explanation: here I am changing the size of *studentClass, is it considered "it's content" ? thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's dereferencing the pointer, so accessing or modifying what it points to.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the fact mentioned by Stephan Lechner that code should either leave the allocation alone or null out the pointer to it (as opposed to freeing the memory without nulling out the pointer) there are a couple of other issues I see:

1. If a caller isn't expected to recover from out-of-memory conditions, allocation functions shouldn't return when they occur.  Instead they should signal the fault (perhaps by raising a signal) and then exit (if signalling the fault didn't already force an exit).  Having a function guarantee that it will never return unsuccessfully can greatly simplify client code.
2. If the function is going to use a global variable to hold the size of the allocation, it should use a global pointer to the allocation.  If it is going to use an object-pointer identified by a passed-in address, it should use an object count that is also identified by a passed-in address.

I can see four good approaches to fixing that second issue:

1. Pass in a double-indirect pointer as you do now, but also pass a pointer to an integer-type object holding the number of students.
2. Pass in a pointer to a structure which holds a student pointer and the number of students.
3. Define a structure which holds a count and a flexible array member of the student type, and keep a pointer to that rather than to the first student.
4. As above, but keep a pointer to the first student (as opposed to the start of the allocated region).  This would require that any code that uses malloc/realloc/free be adjusted to offset the pointers exchanged with such functions.

Approaches #3 and #4 could have a slight advantage if the number of students can grow instead of shrink.  If the size of the allocated region shrinks to zero, there would be no way to determine whether a request to `realloc` a region's size to zero bytes succeeds (if the region previously had a zero size, the Standard would allow `realloc(prevPtr,0)` to return null after having successfully released the previous allocation, but the Standard would also allow the `realloc` to fail (and return null) without having released the previous allocation.